# Portable way to set custom URL scheme handler for all users

Tags: portability, url, xdg, xdg-open

I already know how to create a custom URL scheme and set its handler using xdg-utils:

```
xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler name handler.desktop
```

However, the command affects only the current user. Is there any way (preferably using xdg-utils, as portability is my concern) to register `handler.desktop` as the application to handle `name` URLs for all users on my system (when any user runs `xdg-open name://something`, `handler.desktop` should be called?

Update: For my Ubuntu machine, appending a line into `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` seems to work:

```
x-scheme-handler/name=handler.desktop
```

Is this method portable?